# Shouldn't there be a Particle for Changing Left-handed to Right-handed Particles and Vice Versa?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, chirality

There must be a particle for changing Left-handed to Right-handed particles:

$$e_l + Z^0_T \to e_r$$

Where $Z^0_T$ has Weak Isospin = 1/2 and Spin = 1, and no other quantum numbers.

Comment: You mean: "Where is my error?"? You do understand this type of vertex works for the Higgs, and ***why***. Can you ensure Lorentz invariance of your vertex for a vector particle intermediator? How??

Comment: Note that, while the Higgs does this, the Higgs has spin zero. Why do you like spin one?

Comment: I don't know how to ensure Lorentz invariance since I don't know the corresponding equation. It's spin = 1 because a left handed electron has spin -1/2 and a right handed electron has spin 1/2, I recon because one has spin in the direction of motion and the other against it.

Comment: The Higgs got mass so how does the equation conserve mass/energy?

Comment: In its rest frame, a L or R chiral electron may have its spin of magnitude 1/2 point in absolutely any direction. Your reaction is understood as a QFT vertex which entails virtual particles, covered in the field; energy-momentum is conserved in the vertex, even for freakishly off-shell particles.

Comment: Their spin quantum number must differ by 1 since electrons must be free from choice of coordinates. Their motion could also be in any direction but spin has to be parallel or antiparallel to motion.

Comment: You are thinking about helicity, not chirality?? Have you appreciated how the photon of the Compton effect avoids this? Clarify. Why "has to"??

Comment: Otherwise it is neither left nor right handed.

Answer (score 0):

As dictated by Lorentz invariance, there is no such spin 1 particle. Why would you ask? I gather you appreciate the crucial difference between [chirality & helicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)#Chirality_and_helicity) for massive particles, and never use L and R for helicity, which is $\pm$.

You recall the Higgs scalar (spinless), *h*, does, indeed, flip the chirality of fermions, coupling as
$$
{m_e\over v}(\overline {e_R} h e_L +\overline {e_L} h e_R).
$$
This term is non-vanishing since the chiral projectors slip past the $\gamma^0$ implicit in the overbar and flip to the other kind,  enforcing the opposite chirality of the particle destroyed by the term. So the term destroys a L electron and a Higgs, and creates a R electron; and the same for R to L.

But this is impossible to arrange for your conjectural ${\mathbb Z}$ vector particle, as Lorentz invariance would dictate a term proportional to
$$
g(c \overline {e_R}~\gamma_\mu  {\mathbb Z}^\mu e_L +c'\overline {e_L} ~\gamma_\mu  {\mathbb Z}^\mu e_R)=0,
$$
as now the projectors would wade through a total of *two* gamma matrices, and stay the same: thereby killing (projecting out) their complementary chirality ones. No such term possible.

By dramatic contrast, in real life, the SM, the actual  ($Y=T_3=0$) *Z*  boson coupling preserves chirality,
$$
g(c \overline {e_R}~\gamma_\mu   Z ^\mu e_R +c'\overline {e_L} ~\gamma_\mu  Z ^\mu e_L),
$$
and you may have learned about the peculiar/remarkable fact that *c* is different from *c'*...

Of course, the mass of the lepton will flip chirality upon propagation in no time (estimate it), and so would a virtual *Z* via the equivalence-theorem would-be-goldston scalar in its belly.